# Cutkosky rules for excited states of the proton

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics

Normally, the Cutkosky rules mean that the cut propagators $\frac{1}{p^2-m^2+i\epsilon}$ are replaced by $-2\pi i\delta(p^2-m^2)$. In the case of excited states of the proton, the denominators have the form $\frac{1}{p^2-m^2+im\Gamma+i\epsilon}$ instead. How do I apply the Cutkosky rules here? Replacing with $-2\pi i\delta(p^2-m^2+im\Gamma) $ does not make much sense to me, since we would set $p^2$ to a complex number.

Comment: Cutkosky’s rules are for obtaining the discontinuity of a real-analytic scattering amplitude across cuts that lie on the real energy axis.  The finite width Breit-Wigner form for the propagator does not yield such an amplitude.

Comment: Can I rewrite the propagator in a way that the Cutkosky rules can be applied?